# splitting file path in visual c++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, split

I have a filepath that can have both / and \ and multiple of them, for example

\\abc/tr\record.csv

or

\\re/nst/opr\etc/some/nov\

I would like to get the first 2 pieces of it (abc and tr in the first example and re and nst in the second)

How can I do this in visual C++? (windows) 
With regexes or some msdn function? Maybe there is an msdn function to normalize the filepath to all \ or all / and only one of them? (I cant use extra libs like boost)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply "parse" the string in a loop if you are sure that you only ever need encounter \ and / as path separator. Yes, you can use a regex or something more complicated, but it's a pretty simple problem as is.

Something like this - note, the code is untested and most likely won't compile, but it'd illustrate the algorithm:

```
std::string::citerator beg = path.cbegin();
std::string::citerator end = path.cend();
unsigned separator_count = 0;
while(beg != end && separator_count < 4)
{
  if (*beg == '/' || *beg == '\\')
    ++separator_count;
  ++beg;
}

std::string extracted_path = (separator_count == 3)
  ? path.substr(path.cbegin(), std::distance(path.cbegin(), beg))
  : std::string();
```